# Does symfony have a service to parse HTML content?

Tags: symfony, parsing

I wonder if the Symfony framework has component to make process of parsing easier than using cUrl library?

Comment: curl does not "parse HTML content".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check out the [DomCrawler Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html)

```
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

$html = <<<'HTML'
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p class="message">Hello World!</p>
        <p>Hello Crawler!</p>
    </body>
</html>
HTML;

$crawler = new Crawler($html);

foreach ($crawler as $domElement) {
    var_dump($domElement->nodeName);
}
```